Cast a List<derivedType> into a List<baseType> without breaking the reference
I have multiple lists of type ArmorBase and WeaponBase that inherit the ItemBase class.
I also have a List that represents the current selected item List
    public List<ItemBase> currentItemBasesList;

    public List<ArmorBase> helmetBasesList;
    public List<ArmorBase> chestplateBasesList;
    public List<ArmorBase> shoulderguardsBasesList;
    public List<ArmorBase> armguardsBasesList;
    public List<ArmorBase> thighguardsBasesList;
    public List<ArmorBase> bootsBasesList;
    public List<ArmorBase> shieldBasesList;
    public List<ArmorBase> capeBasesList;
    public List<WeaponBase> weaponBasesList;



But I am having trouble when assigning these lists to the List currentItemBasesList.
My first thought was:
currentItemBasesList = chestplateBasesList.Cast<ItemBase>().ToList();

My problem is that this way I break the referente to the List chestplateBasesList; So if I remove any item from the List currentItemBasesList, it doesnt update in the List chestplateBasesList.
What are my options in this case? Thanks in advance

Use ObservableCollection or BindingList instead of List. Subscribe to CollectionChanged or ListChanged event and implement the necessary logic for changing the second collection.

You can't. Because List<T> has methods that take a T parameter and others that return a T. Casting would break the rules of one of those methods. Otherwise known as variance https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/.

ideally these should be a view of the main list


Cast a List<derivedType> into a List<baseType>

You cant, since list is not variant. If that was possible you could add a WeaponBase to your currentItemBasesList, making your chestplateBasesList contain a weapon.
This is likely an indication that you need to reconsider whatever it is you are doing. It is difficult to provide suggestions without an understanding of what you are trying to do.
In some cases it is sufficient to just use a covariant interface, like IReadOnlyList<T> instead of List<T>, but that will not work if you plan on adding or removing values.
Or Perhaps you need a higher level of abstraction, something like a non generic IItemsView that provide whatever functionality you need for different kinds of items, with different implementations for each type of items.
Or you could start by just putting everything into the same list, and use filtering to select a specific type, since IEnumerable is evaluated lazily the helmets would reflect any changes to allItems:
var allItems = new List<ItemBase>(){...};
var helmets = allItems.OfType<ArmorBase>().Where(armor => armor.Type == ArmorTypes.Helmet);

